# IIS upload large file ever http response 502

Tags: iis, http, asp.net, timeout, upload

I can't upload a large file (1,16 go) on my net.core API throught IIS.

I set this values on my web.config

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="100000" maxRequestLength="2000000" />

<security>
   <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
       <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2000000000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>

<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ConfigurationNode.dll" **requestTimeout="00:20:00"** stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" />
```

whatever value I set at :

> **requestTimeout**

I get a http code 502 at the end of the time, for example if i put 10 minutes after 10 minutes I get a code 502.

[DevTools timing tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W15j.png)

thanks for all

EDIT: I just realized that the maximum size that I can upload is 128mo

Comment: Maybe you need more than ten minutes depends on the file size

Comment: What size is 'large'?

Comment: I increase the timeout allotted to 20 minutes i have the same issue
Greg: 1,16  Go

Comment: Large file upload should be done in async mode to avoid timeout